# how to release CCLayer's child node in cocos2d-x

Tags: memory-management, memory-leaks, cocos2d-x, autorelease

the cocos2d-x reference count function sounds very attractive,but when i use it on my project,i found the "out of memory" problem still can't been eliminated,e.g there is a very simple case as below:

when i release the CCLayer,its child node will not released in the meantime.right?do i have  to manually release the child node one by one before releasing the CCLayer as below?

```
void MyLayer::releaseChildren(){
    CCArray * children = this->getChidren();//"this" pointer is the CCLayer
    CCObject * obj;
    CCARRAY_FOREACH(childen,obj)
    {
      CCNode * child = static_cast<Node*>(obj);
      child->release;
    }
}
```

if you can share your practice of your project ,that will be very helpful for me

Answer (score 1):

What I can make sure is that you **NEED NOT** manually release the child nodes.

Usually, if you have entered a `CCLayer`'s `release` methods, you most likely called `removeChild` or `removeFromParent` or other similar methods.

And it would remove and release the child nodes before removing the parent node. You could look at [`Node::removeChild()`](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.6/d3/d82/classcocos2d_1_1_node.html#ad4548a27e089986fad71fdc09220fd32) <s>and [`Node::detachChild`](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.4/d3/d82/classcocos2d_1_1_node.html#aca733f7a1326e3a239c6e68c9900e1b8)</s> for detail.

**EDIT 2015-05-26** `Node::detachChild` was removed in versions > 3.4; use `Node::removeChild` or [`Node::removeFromParent`](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.6/d3/d82/classcocos2d_1_1_node.html#a56ae8e6cfb617d66b934e10dfc6f2bdc) instead.

And your "out of memory" problem may be caused by other problem, like not unschedule, nor removing notification observer, nor other things.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
CCArray * children = this->getChildren();//"this" pointer is the CCLayer
CCObject * obj;
CCARRAY_FOREACH(children,obj)
{
    CCNode * child = static_cast<CCNode*>(obj);
    this->removeChild(child, true); //Remove the child 
    child->release();
    CC_SAFE_DELETE(child);
}
```